# Не могу никак зарегистрировать аккаунт google

Tags: google-chrome, регистрация

Короче, проблема такая, мне отдали телефон человека который не смог разобраться с проблемой. А проблема заключается в том что после полного сброса настроек, а точнее hard reset, он смог каким то образом попасть в рабочий стол телефона, но половину функций работает, но большая проблема это именно сам аккаунт google который запрашивает везде, просит типо пин код, либо синхронизорованну почту которую никто не знает. Как это обойти? Потому что всё уже перепробовали, а писать в тех поддержку тоже не получается из-за запроса аккаунта. Новый Аккаунт уже есть для регистрации, так же доступны некие приложения скачивать, только уже от Tecno store. А гугл плей нерабоет, сами знаете почему. Вот что делать? Помогите. А буду отвечать на ваши ответы

Телефон марки TECNO GO 2024. Версия андроид 13